# How to load and render templates in Play! 2.0?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

In the old Play! v1 template loading was very simple. But now I'm at a loss to figure out how I can use Scala templates in a similar fashion to the method below:

```
val template = TemplateLoader.load(templateName)
val body = template.render(templateBinding)
```

The use case above is rendering a template to be used for an email in Scala.

The new Scala API has a similar class for working with templates http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Html but how would you load the template? Should I just bite the bullet and import Groovy templates? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Templates are now compiled java classes. you don't really need to "load" them.

Looks like what you are trying to do is a tag. In which case I would recommend reading this page: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates

Each template is a function and can be easily called with `html.Mails.emailtemplate(tags)` and use the `render()` method to build the template. If you only need the text or body of the template, you can also use a syntax like `html.Mails.emailtemplate(tags).body`.

A particular use case related to the question can be seen in this mailer class for Play! in Gist: https://gist.github.com/2210788

Comment: So if that's correct, I can do it in 1 line not 2? `val body = views.html.CustomTemplateFolder.emailMsg(arg1,arg2)`? That's nifty. Hope you don't mind if I edit your answer and provide some sample code when I'm done ;)

Comment: If I recall it generate a render() method. the best is to look at the generated scala class somewhere under src_managed. No I don't mind if you edit.